# How do I use a newer perf tool front end with a record from an older perf version

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, perf

I am running perf record on an older version of the kernel on an ARM board. The kernel version is 3.18.21-rt19

The perf version on the board is similarly perf version 3.18.21.

While I can record and use the report feature on this perf, the TUI for report on this version is quite awful/non-existent. Instead of the expandable sections (in the graph mode) it just shows up as a giant scrollable list of functions that is very tough to work with. Also for some reason my C++ function names are not de-mangled so it is really difficult to read it.

Is it possible to some how either:

1. Export the perf.data created on this older ARM kernel to an x86 machine running a newer kernel  and a newer version of perf and use the perf report on said machine. When I try to do that (I run on kernel 4.4.0-31-generic running perf version 4.4.13) I lose all symbols, even though running perf report on the ARM machine shows the symbols just fine (C++ names are still  mangled). I am not sure if this is just because the perf.data format has changed between these kernel versions or if the x86 version is just outright not capable of reading data generated by the ARM machine.
2. Build a newer perf version (at least the front end) for my older kernel that does the de-mangling and exposes the newer better TUI.

Changing the kernel version on my ARM board is not an option for me.

Comment: Building a newer perf user-space tool is possible. Your perf probably was built without TUI. To export perf.data to another machine you should use [`perf archive` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-archive.1.html) which will copy all symbol information with `perf.data` (or try to copy files from root fs or full image of root fs, as `perf.data` after `perf record` has only instruction addresses, not full obejct/functions maps).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Export the perf.data

Exporting of `perf.data` should be supported with `perf archive` command, check man perf-archive - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-archive.1.html

> `perf-archive` - Create archive with object files with build-ids found in perf.data file
>
> ```
>   perf archive [file]
> ```
>
> This command runs perf-buildid-list --with-hits, and collects the
>          files with the buildids found so that analysis of perf.data contents
>          can be possible on another machine.

There is no example of using perf archive in the Perf Tutorial: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial but mentioned in http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/LinuxConJapan2015-DynamicProbes.pdf#page=22 "What’s the Buildid-cache? .. This also allows us to analyse perf.data from remote machine (perf-archive does that)"

It can be hard to use perf with another architecture (x86) to ream ARM files, so you probably may try some ARM system emulator (like `qemu`/`qemu-system-arm`) with some recent ubuntu/arm or linaro/arm iso or root image (they should have full-featured `perf`).

You may also try to upload better version of perf utility (built by you or copied from ubuntu or linaro) to your  board  - perf user-space tool is compatible with perf_events kernel interface over wide range of kernel versions, and it can read `perf.data` recorded with different version of perf tool.

Comment: This seems like the right way to make it work. My perf version shows archive as one of the available commands but when I run perf archive it says:

`perf: 'archive' is not a perf-command. See 'perf --help'.

Did you mean this?
 archive`

Comment: Rajiv, This is strange, but I see no 'archive' command in perf's `main()` and internal [command list](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/perf.c?v=3.18#L36) too, but there is `perf-archive.sh` bash script - try it - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/perf-archive.sh?v=3.18 (download from the https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/perf-archive.sh). This can probably be an error in perf's documentation (if only it has documentation).

Comment: I was able to run perf-archive.sh. I noticed that the ~/.debug folder only had files for [kernel.kallsyms]. So when I use the archive file on another host and populate its ~/.debug folder with the archive file's contents, perf-report can resolve the kernel symbols. I am not sure how to get the other symbols. perf-buildid-list --with-hits shows entries like `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 /lib/libc-2.21.so` for all entries besides [kernel.kallsyms] on the host AMR board. Not sure where perf report on the ARM board can find these symbols.

Comment: Rajiv, try to run `ldd ./your_program` and manually copy all listed binary files from ARM to the host machine.

Comment: Accepting this answer. I have issues with my toolchain that is preventing me from making this work, but looks like these steps will work fine once I get these issues sorted out.